# How to get the already stored payment card data in iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, payment, payment-request-api

The goal is to get user's payment card data in iOS/Android apps, but not by just having them enter it. I'd like them to be able to use a platform-wide context which already keeps the payment card details. Much like the [Payment Request API](https://paymentrequest.show) on the web.

I looked at ApplePay and Google Pay but they don't seem to directly provide the payment cards details.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Pay](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/) and [Apple wallet](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204003) would be closest to the linked payments request api on the web. But keep in mind that even those wouldn't give you the card data directly.

Google Pay only works with specific 'Google Pay Processors' which handle the actual transaction (See list of processors [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/)), so you never get the actual credit card data and cannot perform the payment processing yourself.
I assume Apple has the same restrictions.

Another issue you might have is that they are not globally supported.

Have you thought about using paypal maybe? Found a cordova plugin [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin).

Comment: That's a bummer. I really do need the payment card data directly. I'm developing payment mechanism for a country that does not support neither PayPal, nor Braintree, nor Stripe, nor Adyen, nor Nothing.

Comment: Yeah that's the way most of these payment APIs on mobile work. Maybe you could think about integrating a credit card scanning library which will extract and prefill the credit card data.

Answer (score 0):

You have good options for both iOS and Android.

For iOS look to Apple Pay -> https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/
For Android look to Google Pay -> https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/

Comment: Neither of these give me the payment card details like the Web API does. I need the data directly.